# How to add a quantity condition to a regex without including the quantity into the matching group?

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a match only if an additional quantity condition is true.

Example (which is fine):

Regex: `-(START.*?)_\d+(?=-END)`

Input: `test-START_one_two_three_4-END`

Match Group1: `START_one_two_three`

Anyways I want to add an additional check that inside the group match, there should be `_{3,4}` characters. But not followed by each other directly.

So I'd have to create an additional non-capturing group with `(?:...)`.
What I tried: looking 4 times for `_*` until the `-END`:

`(?:(?:_[^_]*){4}-END)`

But adding this into the regex won't create a match anymore. Why?

https://regex101.com/r/MHzWBr/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a lookahead here:

```
-(START(?=(?:_[^_]*){3,4}-END).*?)_+\d+(?=-END) 
         ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHzWBr/3)

Now, `(?=(?:_[^_]*){3,4}-END)` is a positive lookahead that makes sure that, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

- `(?:_[^_]*){3,4}` - three or four repetitions of `_` followed with any 0+ chars other than `_`
- `-END`  - a literal `-END` string.
- `.*?`

Note that if you want to match the *closest* window between `-START` and `-END` you need to exclude the `.` and `[^_]` from matching the start of the `-START` and `-END` patterns:

```
-(START(?=(?:_(?:(?!-(?:END|START))[^_])*){3,4}-END)(?:(?!-(?:END|START)).)*)_+\d+(?=-END)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHzWBr/6)

The `(?:(?!-(?:END|START)).)*` pattern is a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: TY! That indeed was my intention, but was probably confused due to the nested non-capturing group (which I don't need indeed).

Comment: @membersound You need the non-capturing group to quantify a *sequence* of patterns.

Comment: That regex doesn't ensure that the two `-END` are the same, e.g. it'll match `test-START_4-END_one_two_three-END`, but that's not right. --- It would probably be better to *replace* the `.*?` with a pattern that matching the 3-4 times underscore blocks, instead of mixing in a zero-width lookahead,

Comment: @Andreas could you give an improvement? Of course I'd only would want to match until the first `-END`, and thus get no match at all.

Comment: @Andreas Given current conditions, it does not make any difference. `.*?` just matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars and `[^_]` matches any char other than  `_`, and that can be restricted easily with `(?:(?!-END).)*`. See https://regex101.com/r/MHzWBr/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and if I'm sure a `-` could only occur right before the `-END`, could I as well replace `.*?` with `[^-]*?` = match anything but `-`?

Comment: @membersound You may even use `[^-]*`, the greedy quantifier will make the engine get to the match quicker. Negating sequences of chars is more difficult and less efficient, so if you can use the negated character class, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to do this without a positive lookahead and repeat 2 - 3 times an underscore followed by 1+ times not an underscore.

You could also turn the positive lookahead at the end into a match.

```
-(START(?:_[^_]+){2,3})_\d+(?=-END)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sj1NmW/1)

That will match:

- `-` Match -
- `(` Capturing group

  - `START(?:_[^_]+){2,3}` Match START and repeat 2-3 times an underscore followed by not an underscore
- `)_\d+` Close group, match `_` and 1+ digits
- `(?=-END)` Assert what is on the right is `-END` (Or match -END without the lookahead)